# WordPress front end avatar upload not working

Tags: php, wordpress, image-upload

I am trying to change the avatar from the front end, but I am not able to change it.

The error I got:

> "You don't have permission to attach files to this post."

whether I am trying with the admin account.

What should be the issue? I am trying this on HIREBEE theme version 1.3.1

Sample code:

```
<?php if ( $hrb_options->avatar_upload ): ?>
  <div class="large-2 small-2 columns upload-gravatar">
    <?php hrb_gravatar_media_manager( $current_user->ID, array( 'id' => '_app_gravatar' ) );  ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="large-3 small-3 columns user-meta-info right">
    <?php 
       the_hrb_user_bulk_info( $current_user->ID, array( 'show_gravatar' => array( 'size' => 75 ) ) ); 
     ?>
</div>
```

You can check this theme here: [Hirebee 1.3.1 theme link](http://prefiles.com/6g1yt6stdf4u/Appthemes.Hirebee.v1.3.1.rar)

Comment: it is a default permissions issue. Please check user permissions for the `upload_files`

Comment: Do u have any reference site for this issue ? i am applying following permissions when user registers for the first time :  $caps[HRB_ROLE_CLIENT] = array(
  'edit_projects',
  'delete_projects',
  'edit_published_projects', 'upload_media',
  'embed_media','edit_published_posts'
 );

 $caps[HRB_ROLE_SUPPLIER] = array(
  'edit_bids','upload_media','edit_projects',
  'embed_media' ,'edit_published_posts'
 );

 $caps[HRB_ROLE_BOTH] = array_merge( $caps[HRB_ROLE_CLIENT], $caps[HRB_ROLE_SUPPLIER] );

Comment: [WPFront User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/) This will may be help you.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd... i have tried this this plugin but still the problem is not solved.